# What is satisfactory progress for a postdoc?

Tags: united-states, postdocs, career-path, materials-science

I am a first-year postdoc in the field of material science, and this is a new experience for me. The most difficult question here is self-evaluation.
For example, during this year I have prepared an annual project report, 2 manuscripts (one was submitted, the second one is under discussion), work on on the draft for 3rd manuscript, supervised 2 students, applied to microgrant (unsuccessfully), prepared a project proposal for own grant. The most disturbing question for me is a publication activity, I feel it could be better.
Thus, the main question is what is the satisfactory progress for the postdoc in general?

Comment: You will have to mention the discipline and country.  In some discipline, one journal is considered good.  In others, a minimum of 10 per year is considered 'good or normal'.

Comment: Satisfactory progress is whatever puts you on track to be competitive for permanent jobs at the appropriate time.

Comment: The discipline is Materials science (luminescent materials), US university

Comment: To echo Alexander Woo's comment, you could try looking at publication records of recent tenure-track hires in your area at a variety of schools, to get a sense of how competitive the market is.  (Also, ask people in your department!)

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus "10 per year is considered 'good or normal'" -- that sounds extreme. Nobody, certainly not a young researcher at the postdoc level, can have the capacity to write ten papers a year.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth in some areas, that's quite the norm.  I'm thinking of materials engineering.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus Are these machine-generated papers that only show a 3d structure of a specific molecule or crystal structure, with each paper just 5 pages long? And how many co-authors do these papers have? Ten papers as a minimum just seems impossible.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I'm not from that area.   These are not machine generated papers... unless you mean students/staff are 'machines'.    I'm referring to first authored papers only.  If you add co-authors, they go up to 20 or more easily.  Yes, the papers are short.  Most document some combination of materials and their properties.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus Hm.. I agree and disagree with you. Publish 10 papers per year is close to extreme and possible only if you have found a "gold strike" and you are in a flow of the group. In my best time I published 6-8 articles (not letters or short) per year but I had spent ~2 years on the preliminary work before that. And all of that was articles that were written by me where I was the first author. I know guys who have 10+ articles per year but technically most of them just did only specific measurements of the materials.